# How to implement a program that accepts a file path as its argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, command-line-arguments

I have written a python program that uses values from text files. In order to get the text files, one of the requirements is that it must be able to accept the file path as an argument in the terminal. I am trying to use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy

x = str(input("Enter directory path: \n"))
data = numpy.loadtxt(open(x), int)
```

However , when I run the program in the terminal like this:

```
MBP:Game test$ python GameOfLife.py 
Enter directory path:
/Users/test/Google Drive/Game.py
```

I get the following error afterwards.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Game.py", line 5, in <module>
x = str(input("Enter directory path\n"))
File "<string>", line 1
/Users/test/Google Drive/Game.py
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to python, so any help would be really great.

Comment: Are you sure you are on Python 3.X?  This looks like an error you would get with `input` on Python 2.X.

Comment: You are not using Python 3. Input string gets `eval`ed, which is a behavior of Python 2 `input()` function.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "accept the file path as an argument in the terminal"? Is the user supposed to run the program and then enter a path, or should they provide the path when starting the program, e.g. `py Game.py path/dir/file.py`?

Comment: I am using Python3. they provide the path when starting the program. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

string must be put in quotes;

Try this:

```
"/Users/test/Google Drive/Game.py"
```

In addition you can use function `raw_input` instead of input. `input` function run your input text as python code but with `raw_input` you could input anything without any constraints.

so you can use

```
x = raw_input("Enter directory path: \n")
```

instead of

```
x = str(input("Enter directory path: \n"))
```

Comment: Or they could switch to `raw_input` and avoid the insecurity of `input` altogether.

Comment: Also, there are no backslashes to escape here, so I'm not sure why you mention that.

Comment: While technically this does solve the problem, no user should be expected to have to quote their input to use the program.

Comment: Hi I am using Python 3, so this does not seem to work here

Comment: In python 3, `raw_input` replaced with `input`. If you used python 3, you should't get that error, so you probably ran it in a python 2 environment. Run `python --version` or  print `sys.version` to make sure that your python is 3 :)